# $(x_1,x_2,…,x_{117})A$=$(x_{117},x_1,x_2,…,x_{116})$ Find detA

Tags: linear-algebra

A is a matrix such that $(x_1,x_2,…,x_{117})A$=$(x_{117},x_1,x_2,…,x_{116})$. 
 
Find $detA$

Is the answer 1?

Comment: Hint: Can you take this to small cases? What does the matrix do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
x^{T} \mathbf{A} & = \hat{x} \\
%
\left[ \begin{array}{ccccccc}
 x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3} & x_{4} & x_{5} & x_{6} & x_{7}
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\hline
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
& = 
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 x_{7} \\ x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ x_{3} \\ x_{4} \\ x_{5} \\ x_{6}
\end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$
$$
\det \mathbf{A} = 1
$$

As pointed out by @lhf, the repeated action keeps shifting the list to the right:
$$
\hat{x}^{T} \mathbf{A} =
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  x_{6} \\ x_{7} \\ x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ x_{3} \\ x_{4} \\ x_{5}
\end{array} \right]
$$

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* What does $A^{2}$ do? What does $A^{117}$ do?

Comment: What is 'action'? What does it mean?

Comment: Is the answer 1?

Comment: @Kyotomath, yes, and it follows from my hint directly after you notice that $A$ is real.